# D3 javscript: How to add a div in aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, d3

I am trying to create a map hierarchy visual aura component using D3 library and d3 tree and d3.hierachy methods. The original code had circles in place for the nodes, but I want to append a div so that I can have a square box with information/fields placed within the div. The problem is that I cant seem to get any formatting to show up on the aura component. Maybe it has to do with the strict rules on interacting with the DOM in salesforce, however I am not sure because I'm still fairly new to development in general.

Here is a pic of the component:

[image: Component]

CSS

[image]

Relevant Js
[image]

The commented code is of course the circle that was previously there and that I am trying to replace with a div having a border. Can I even do this within salesforce?

Component cmp

[image]

Helper js

```
({
drawOrgChart : function(component, event, helper) {

  var treeData ={
                  "name": "Durango Holding",
                  "children": [
                      { "name": "Durango Trucking"},
                      { "name": "Durango Leasing" },
                      { "name": "VW",
                        "children" : [
                            { "name" : "Golf"},
                            { "name" : "Beetle"}
                        ] 
                      },
                      { "name": "Hyundai"},
                   ]
                 };
  
  console.log(treeData);
    
 //setting the dimensions and margins of the diagram
 var margin = {top: 40, right:30, bottom:50, left:30};
 var width = 1260 - margin.left - margin.right;
 var height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
 //Declare a tree Layout and assign its size
 var treemap = d3.tree()
             .size([width, height]);
    
 //Assigns the data to hierarchy using parent-child relationships
 var nodes = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d){
                    return d.children;
                 });
 console.log(nodes);
    
 /*NOTE: This assigns a range of properties to each node including (node.data, node.depth, node.height, node.parent, node.children)
 We are telling the function to use the "children" element from treeData to generate property of the nodes. */
    
 //Map the node data to tree Layout
 nodes = treemap(nodes);
 console.log(nodes);
    
 
 //Append the Map(SVG) to the body of the Lightning Component
 var svg = d3.select("body")   
         .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
 //Add All Links between nodes
 var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
           .data(nodes.descendants().slice(1)) //We are not including the main 'root' node as since its drawn from child to parent.
           .enter()
           .append("path")
           .attr("class", "link")
           .attr("fill", "none") //Including all the styles directly here as the Style configured is not applied to lighting component.
           .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
           .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
               .attr("d", function(d){  //Here Attribute 'd' is used to describe the curve. Using Bezier Curve
                return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
                    + "L" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
                    + " " + d.parent.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
                    + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y
            });
 console.log(nodes.descendants());
 console.log(nodes.descendants().slice(1));
    
 //Add Each Node as a Group - Ie, setting up a group
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                   .data(nodes.descendants())
                   .enter()
                   .append("g")
                        .attr("class", "node node--leaf")
                    .attr("transform", function(d){
                            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                    });
    
 //Add a circle to the node
 /*
 node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", 15)
     .attr("fill", "#fff")
     .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
     .attr("stroke-width", "3px");


node.append("div")
    .style("border","2px solid black");;



node.append("rect")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 225)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("rx", 3);

                             */
node.append("div")
    .attr("class", "box");

    
 //Add Text to the node
 node.append("text")
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .attr("y", function(d){ return d.children ? -20 : 20;})
     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
     .text(function(d) {return d.data.name; });

}
})
```

error:
[image]

code updated:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
```

You can't use `document.body` and apply styles to it, because it is protected by [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer), and you are reaching outside your component's container.

You need to provide a valid element within your own component:

```
<aura:component>
  <div aura:id="container">
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

And then hand that element to d3:

```
var svg = d3.select(component.find("container"))
```

You can also use a `lightning:container`, described in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/219450/2984).

Comment: ok I updated code but am getting an undefined error. Did I update it wrong?

Comment: The updated code and error are in the og post also. At bottom. Thanks @sfdcfox